# Converting GMT date format to locale based format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nslocale

How can we convert NSDate object in GMT format to the date format with current locale/device settings?

For example if a device is in US and in PDT time zone then I want to convert GMT time to its equivalent PDT time.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, you cannot convert an `NSDate` to another time zone because `NSDate` has no conception of time zones whatsoever. An `NSDate` object simply represents a single point in (absolute) time, regardless of time zone.

Whenever you want to display a date to the user, you should create an `NSDateFormatter`. By default, it automatically displays time in the user's time zone. You can override this with `-[NSDateFormatter setTimeZone:]`.

Comment: Ok. Got it. One question -- How can we know the current timezone of the device?

Comment: See `NSTimeZone`'s `+systemTimeZone`, `+defaultTimeZone`, and `+localTimeZone`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `NSDate` method `descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:` passing in the appropriate timezone. If you just use the `description` method you get the date/time in the current timezone (so if the device is set to PDT the time will be in PDT).